# How to cancel UIActivityItemProvider and don't show activity?

Tags: nsoperation, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I'm using `UIActivityItemProvider` subclass to provide custom data. But sometimes getting data fails and I don't want to present activity (e.g. message composer). Tried `[self cancel]` and `return nil;` in `item` method, but message composer still shows (with empty message).

Comment: I'd like to know if anyone's figured out a workaround for this, too. It's definitely an iOS SDK bug. I'd suggest lodging a radar for this one.

Comment: I have the same issue. Still looking for a workaround as well.

Comment: And still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you dismiss the UIActivityViewController before returning from -(id)item it will not present the users chosen activity.

To do this you first need to grab the activityViewController in activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem. In -(id)item run code in a dispatch_async to update progress and dismiss on complete / error which I'm doing using a promise lib.

In your subclass of UIActivityItemProvider do something similar to the example below.

```objc
-(id) activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController
{ self.avc = activityViewController;
  return NSURL;
}

-(id)item
{ __block BOOL fileProcDone = NO;
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
  { self.pvc = [[ProgressAlertVC alloc] init];
    [self.vc presentViewController:self.pvc animated:YES completion:nil];
    [[[[self promiseMakeFile]
    progressed:^(float progress)
    { self.pvc.progress = progress;
    }]
    fulfilled:^(id result)
    { [self.pvc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
      { fileProcDone = YES;
      }];
    }]
    failed:^(NSError *error)
    { [self.pvc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
      { [self.vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
        { fileProcDone = YES;
        }];
      }];
    }];
  });
  while (!fileProcDone)
  { [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
  }; 
  return NSURL;
}
```

> This will result in a console log message from activity extensions but as long as they deal correctly with errors things should be fine. If you return nil from -(id)activityViewController: itemForActivityType: you don't get console errors but will get the users chosen activity even if you dismiss the UIActivityViewController at this point.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to call the `cancel` method of UIActivityItemProvider. Since UIActivityItemProvider is an NSOperation, calling `cancel` will mark the operation cancelled.

At that point, you have a few options to actually stop the long running task, depending on the structure of your task. You could override the `cancel` method and do your cancellation there, just be sure to call `[super cancel]` as well. The second option is the check the value of `isCancelled` within the `item` method.

#### An example item provider

```swift
import UIKit
import Dispatch

class ItemProvider: UIActivityItemProvider {

    override public var item: Any {
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

        let message = "This will stop the entire share flow until you press OK. It represents a long running task."
        let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Hello", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction.init(title: "OK", style: .default, handler:
            { action in
                semaphore.signal()
        })
        let cancel = UIAlertAction.init(title: "CANCEL", style: .destructive, handler:
            { [weak self] action in
                self?.cancel()
                semaphore.signal()
        })

        alert.addAction(action)
        alert.addAction(cancel)

        //Truly, some hacking to for the purpose of demonstrating the solution
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController?.presentedViewController!.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        // We can block here, because our long running task is in another queue
        semaphore.wait()

        // Once the item is properly cancelled, it doesn't really matter what you return
        return NSURL.init(string: "blah") as Any
    }
}
```

#### In the view controller, start a share activity like this.

```swift
    let provider = ItemProvider.init(placeholderItem: "SomeString")
    let vc = UIActivityViewController.init(activityItems: [provider], applicationActivities: nil)

    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I implemented this example, however it doesn't work on iOS14. When I click on any app on sharing intent nothing happens